# Error writing to S3 using TextIO.write() (Google Dataflow)

Tags: java, amazon-s3, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a Google Dataflow code similar to the below

```
import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.TextIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.fs.ResourceId;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.*;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Create;

public class S3Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().create();
        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

        ResourceId outputDir = FileSystems.matchNewResource("s3://my-bucket/temp/", true);

        pipeline
                .apply("New",
                        Create.of("Hello World!!")
                )
                .apply(
                        "Write to S3",
                        TextIO.write()
                                .to("s3://my-bucket/test.txt")
                                .withoutSharding()
                                .withTempDirectory(outputDir)
                );

        pipeline.run();
    }
}
```

This works to some extent, in that it first creates a temporary file on my S3 bucket. However, when it tries to rename it to my final desired/input filename, it throws the following error.

> Receiver class org.apache.beam.sdk.io.aws.s3.S3FileSystem does not
> define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract
> void rename(java.util.List, java.util.List,
> org.apache.beam.sdk.io.fs.MoveOptions[])' of abstract class
> org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystem.

I guess I have to override or implement a rename() function, but not sure where I'd start on that.

Has anyone tried to write successfully to S3 using TextIO.write()?

EDIT:

Below is the full message in the Run window:

> Dec 24, 2022 4:56:34 PM
> org.apache.beam.sdk.io.WriteFiles$WriteShardsIntoTempFilesFn
> processElement INFO: Opening writer
> 8a0dbf70-a0fc-48dd-92f9-8ff4000a8076 for window
> org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.windowing.GlobalWindow@2dddc1b9 pane
> PaneInfo{isFirst=true, isLast=true, timing=ON_TIME, index=0,
> onTimeIndex=0} destination null Dec 24, 2022 4:56:37 PM
> org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSink$Writer close INFO: Successfully
> wrote temporary file
> s3://my-bucket/temp/.temp-beam-13da7e3e-15a9-4285-a90c-30c7c6dcfe99/9e53ec6a8a0dbf70-a0fc-48dd-92f9-8ff4000a8076
> Dec 24, 2022 4:56:37 PM
> org.apache.beam.sdk.io.WriteFiles$FinalizeTempFileBundles$FinalizeFn
> process INFO: Finalizing 1 file results Dec 24, 2022 4:56:37 PM
> org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSink$WriteOperation
> createMissingEmptyShards INFO: Finalizing for destination null num
> shards 1. Dec 24, 2022 4:56:37 PM
> org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSink$WriteOperation moveToOutputFiles
> INFO: Will copy temporary file
> FileResult{tempFilename=s3://my-bucket/temp/.temp-beam-13da7e3e-15a9-4285-a90c-30c7c6dcfe99/9e53ec6a8a0dbf70-a0fc-48dd-92f9-8ff4000a8076,
> shard=0,
> window=org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.windowing.GlobalWindow@2dddc1b9,
> paneInfo=PaneInfo{isFirst=true, isLast=true, timing=ON_TIME, index=0,
> onTimeIndex=0}} to final location s3://my-bucket/test.txt Exception in
> thread "main" org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException:
> java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class
> org.apache.beam.sdk.io.aws.s3.S3FileSystem does not define or inherit
> an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void
> rename(java.util.List, java.util.List,
> org.apache.beam.sdk.io.fs.MoveOptions[])' of abstract class
> org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystem.    at
> org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner$DirectPipelineResult.waitUntilFinish(DirectRunner.java:374)
> at
> org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner$DirectPipelineResult.waitUntilFinish(DirectRunner.java:342)
> at
> org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run(DirectRunner.java:218)
> at
> org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run(DirectRunner.java:67)
> at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:323)  at
> org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:309)   at
> com.example.S3Test.main(S3Test.java:255) Caused by:
> java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class
> org.apache.beam.sdk.io.aws.s3.S3FileSystem does not define or inherit
> an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void
> rename(java.util.List, java.util.List,
> org.apache.beam.sdk.io.fs.MoveOptions[])' of abstract class
> org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystem.    at
> org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.renameInternal(FileSystems.java:323)
> at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.rename(FileSystems.java:308)
> at
> org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSink$WriteOperation.moveToOutputFiles(FileBasedSink.java:802)
> at
> org.apache.beam.sdk.io.WriteFiles$FinalizeTempFileBundles$FinalizeFn.process(WriteFiles.java:1077)

Comment: Have you tried FileIO.write()?

Comment: Sounds like there is some dependency / JAR issues. Have you imported the same version of Beam components across the project?

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your pipeline... by default **withNumShards()** is set to zero, so it will write to a single file

```
pipeline
        .apply("New",
                Create.of("Hello World!!")
        )
        .apply(
                "Write to S3",
                TextIO.write()
                        .to("s3://my-bucket/test.txt")
                        .withNumShards(1)
                        .withTempDirectory(outputDir)
        );
```

Comment: I still get the same error. Also, I don't want any sharding either.

Comment: It  seems that the S3FileSystem class does not define an implementation of the rename() Try updating the  Apache Beam library to a version that is compatible to S3/ or downgrade the s3, whatever

Comment: While the above code didn't make an impact, it seems my beam-sdks-java-io-amazon-web-services dependency was not my beam.version value.